# Can I use phonePad keyboard with return button?

Tags: ios, uikit

I want to use `.phonePad` or `.numberPad` keyboard.
But it has no return button. I need this.

How can I do it? I should create a custom keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add toolbar on top of keyboard . Use **InputAccessoryView** property of textfield. here is complete tutorial for this

**swift**

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-adding-return-key-in-number.html

**objective c**

https://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/tutorial-creating-a-done-button-on-the-iphone-number-pad-keyboard/

Comment: This is What  I have been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `UIToolbar` above the keyboard using the `UITextField`'s `inputAccessoryView`

Assuming you are using **Swift** :

```
func setupTextfield() {
    // ...
    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView()
    // ...
}

private func inputAccessoryView() -> UIToolbar {
    let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
    keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
    keyboardToolbar.isTranslucent = false
    let flexBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
                                        target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done,
                                        target: self, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
    keyboardToolbar.items = [flexBarButton, doneBarButton]
    return keyboardToolbar
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is simple. I understood easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add toolbar at top of keyboard

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

        toolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelAction)],
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneAction)]];

        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;  
        [toolbar sizeToFit];
        yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }

    -(void)cancelAction{
        yourTextField.text = @"";
    }

    -(void)doneAction{
        NSString *text = yourTextField.text;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned a lot .